# How to decode bitwise matrix?

Tags: python, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I have the following matrix T:

```
-1 19 0
19 -1 0
0 0 -1
```

it's encoding of the sequence `c = 19 19 0`.
The algorithm of encoding is:

```
Tij = c_i AND c_j, if i≠j [bitwise and]
Tii = −1.
```

How to find out the sequence by given matrix?

Comment: I don't think you can reliably under all scenarios. For example, `[X 0 0]` will result in the same matrix no matter the value of X. For your given matrix, it could also be the encoding for `[51 19 0]`.

Comment: Yes, so I can return any encoding if there are multiple of them

Comment: @Randy I found the question in the programming text book, so it can be solved

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in comments, there is not always one solution. They have in common that the bitwise OR of a row of values in the matrix (excluding the -1) will result in the minimum number that obeys the rules. You could also do this column-wise, as the matrix is mirrored by the main diagonal.

Here is the code:

```
def decode(matrix):
    result = [0] * len(matrix)
    for i, row in enumerate(matrix):
        for j, val in enumerate(row):
            if i != j:
                result[i] |= val
    return result
```

If we add the `encode` function, you can easily test with sample data like this:

```
def encode(row):
    return [
        [a & b if i != j else -1 for j, b in enumerate(row)]
        for i, a in enumerate(row)
    ]

matrix = encode([5, 12, 9])  
print(matrix)  # [[-1, 4, 1], [4, -1, 8], [1, 8, -1]]
print(decode(matrix))  # [5, 12, 9]
```